# Why does Threads in BLOCKED state do not get interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, interrupt, blocked-threads

I am working on multithreading in java.
Want to understand if a Thread is in BLOCKED state why it cant be interrupted? And why the thread can be interrupted only if it is in WAIT state? Basically, why do we need two Thread states one which can be interrupted and the other which cant be interrupted?

This question might be very basic but, I am trying to understand things rather than just remembering them.

Comment: *A blocked thread can be interrupted by calling the interrupt() method of Thread class*

Comment: Can you post sample code, the thread stack etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One assumes that you mean cause the thread to stop its current operation and throw an `InterruptedException`?  A thread interrupt in Java is just a flag.  You can call `interrupt()` just fine on a BLOCKED thread and that flag will be seen next time code checks for it.

The principle problem with implementing such a functionality is, how is a keyword (`synchronized`) supposed to throw an exception?  `InterruptedException` is a checked exception, it would not be a useful exercise to have to declare every synchronized method (and block) in the language with `throws InterruptedException`!

An interrupt is a communication tool, it's generally for letting a thread know about a system state it needs to check on.  The name is a legacy carry over/upward from flags set within hardware to let microprocessors know about a particular state (such as new values set on some input pins) that needs to be examined.  Do not read too much into the name "interrupt" and think it's meant to be a tool for breaking the flow of the program within another thread.  It is not.  Hence even the methods that do throw an exception declare it as checked, the other thread is free to ignore it and resume waiting if it wants.  Being able to arbitrarily break another thread's `BLOCKED` state would break the program flow, which is not the purpose.

Comment: Which moron decided to call this flag/notification function 'Interrupt'?

Comment: Thanks @Affe. Recently i came across a situation of deadlocked-threads. I also have a watcher thread which does "Future.canel(true)" after certain interval. Though 'timeout execption occured' and 'future.cancel(true)' was called the deadlocked-threads did not stopped. So i was thinking what is the actual use of 'interrupt' if the other thread cannot be stopped.

Comment: If you upgrade from using `synchronized` directly to using the java.util.concurrent packages then you can cause InterruptedException to be thrown from blocked lock acquisitions.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lockInterruptibly()

Answer (score 0):

Blocked Threads can receive Interrupts. You may have to check `Thread.currentThread().interrupted()` to see whether Thread got interrupt when it was waiting to acquire any resource.

See Also `Lock::lockInterruptibly()`

Answer (score 0):

**A blocked thread can be interrupted**. Here is how interrupt is called on a thread depending on which state it is. From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29):

> The checkAccess method of this thread is invoked, which may cause a
>   SecurityException to be thrown.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible
>   channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status
>   will be set, and the thread will receive a ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a Selector then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection
>   operation, possibly with a non-zero value, just as if the selector's
>   wakeup method were invoked.
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.
>
> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.
>
> Throws: SecurityException - if the current thread cannot modify this
>   thread